# insert into existing row using where() with knex

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

I want to insert data into an existing row with knex.js but I do not see it is clear in the documentation, trying with Where() as in the code below doesn't work. I've seen that there is a npm package called knex-filter that may help in doing so, but I guess there should be a way to do it with knex.js
If anyone knows how to proceed I would be very gratefull.

```
    knex('pets')
    .where({id : petId})
    .insert({image: file.path})
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log('knexjs works!!');
        })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: In insert normally there isn't a where condition  .. (only in select (where) / insert ) .. please explain better

Comment: What I want to do is modify an existing row, I see that the problem maybe that I have to use something different instead of .insert()

Comment: I have posted an asnwer hope useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use update  instead of insert

```
.where('id', petId)
.update({image :file.path})
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the comment from scaisEdge I realized I had to use something different instead of .insert(), and it works using .update().
It makes sense because I don't want to insert but modify or update.

```
     knex('pets')
    .where('id', petId)
    .update({image :file.path})
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log('knexjs works!!');
        })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```